# javascript problem: var a="1";b={a:a},the b variant isn't {"1":1}

Tags: javascript

```
 var a="1";
 b={a:a},
```

the b variant isn't {"1":1},why will this happened?

also want to know if i want to get the result what i want ,how can i solve this problem

Comment: First, this sounds like homework, and when you do this, what do you get as the value of b? Your thoughts on the results and what you are missing could help, as it seems you want the property to be a string and the value to be a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript has a syntax quirk where the bit on the left-hand side of the `:` in an object literal *isn't* an expression like the bit on the right-hand side.

It can be either a quoted string literal, or an identifier token. In the case of an identifier, the token is taken verbatim, as if it were a quoted string. So `{a:"1"}` is the same as `{"a":"1"}`.

If you want to use an expression as a property name, you have to do so using the `[]` property access operator:

```
var b= {};
b[a]= a;
```

Answer (score 1):

because b is assigned to an object literal that has an 'a' property with the value of whatever is in the a var, which is 'i'.  This is how javascript works when defining object literals

```
var x = { prop : value }
```

even if you defined a var prop before you assign x, 'prop' is the literally (pun intended) a key in the object literal.

Also, i think you wanted

```
var b = {a:a};
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `a` in your javascript object is a literal; it will not be treated as a variable and evaluated.

Comment: -1 Srsly, learn what JSON is. It's javascript related question and has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: That's unfair, the JSON rule is identical to the Javascript rule (being that JSON copied its syntax from JS)